# Average of two discrete random variables

Tags: random-variables, average, bayesian-network

I have this graph B<-A->C and I have the joint probability distribution of A and B , P(A,B), and  the joint probability distribution of A and C, P(A,C).
I want to compute the average of B and C.
my attempt is to sum the expectations and divide by 2 as follows :

$AVG(B,C) = ( E[B] + E[C] ) / 2 $

where 2 is the number of random variables I want to compute the average for.
Is this mathematically correct ? or should I multiply the the expectations and divide by 2 ? Note that B is independent of C given A. All the variables are discrete.

Comment: Expectation is always linear, so the expectation of the average of random variables is always the average of the expectations (whenever those expectations exist).

Comment: so I sum the expectations and divide by 2 ? as I did in the equation above ?

Comment: $\mathsf E(\dfrac{A+B}2) = \dfrac{\mathsf E(A)+\mathsf E(B)}{2}$